# Set priorities when loading HTML-page

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cpu

I use a custom javascript on an HTML pageload to decode a 10 second video, using a proprietary codec, not natively supported by the browsers. My problem is that it stalls the browser completely for about 2-3 seconds while the decoding/loading into memory takes place.

Is it possible to actively reduce the amount of allocated CPU-power for specific purposes, so that the browser allocates (for instance) 30% for specific javascript-files? Or perhaps other suggestions in order to prevent the lock-up?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have a look at [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

> Web Workers provide a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks very promising and I'll test it within the next couple of days.